# ScrollTop is not working when tab is changed from left to right in MdTabGroup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I wrote a code that saves the scroll position of the current tab body's div and when we return to that tab it sets the scroll position to the stored value. By logging in the console I find the values stored and retrieved to be correct. But:
When I select a tab that is to the right of the currently active tab, the scroll position can not be set. But the same code sets the scroll position of the div if I select a tab that is towards the left of the currently active tab.

**What is the expected behaviour?**

The scroll position should be set irrespective of the positions of the tab. The code should either work for all cases or none.

**What is the current behaviour?**

When I select a tab that is to the right of the currently active tab, the scroll position can not be set. But the same code sets the scroll position of the div if I select a tab that is towards the left of the currently active tab.

**What are the steps to reproduce?**

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MeQj4zUAQ9qHiFgm7f0J?p=preview)

```
export class TabService {

  public scrollPosition: number = [0, 0, 0];
  public currentTab: number = 0;

  public scrollSave() {
    let el = document.getElementById('content');
    // console.log(this.currentTab);
    this.scrollPosition[this.currentTab] = el.scrollTop;
  }

  public setScroll() {
    let el = document.getElementById('content');  
    if (el.scrollTop !== undefined) {
      el.scrollTop = this.scrollPosition[this.currentTab];
    }
  }
}
```

Go to the second tab. Scroll down to some position. Go to tab 3. Come back to Tab 2. The scroll position should be saved. Repeat the same but go to Tab 1 instead of Tab 3. The scroll position resets to zero.

**Additional Information:**

Calling the function from selectChange does not even save the scroll position correctly. That's why I put that function in focusChange. I have three functions in the original code: one that saves the scroll position, one that selects the content to show after the tab switches and one that sets the scroll position to the saved value. And I want to call the three functions sequentially by calling them from selectChange instead of focusChange. And the saved scroll position is correct in every case.

Comment: what is that you are exactly trying to achieve.? create a working plunker and add a screenshot!

Comment: @Aravind Done the edits and wrote a working plnkr.